# Как можно сократить такое количество проверок?

Tags: javascript

Возможно ли как-то написать такое количество проверок в одну строчку?

```
if (
  itemWhichChange.date.day !== itemWhereChange.date.day ||
  itemWhichChange.date.month !== itemWhereChange.date.month ||
  itemWhichChange.date.year !== itemWhereChange.date.year
)
```

Comment: ``itemWhichChange.date !== itemWhereChange.date`` ?

Comment: Только разве что вынести это в функцию или в объектах добавить функцию по склеиванию трех значений, тогда можно будет выполнить как написано выше

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать массив ключей, которые необходимо сверить и использовать метод [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const keys = ['day', 'month', 'year'];
if (keys.some((key) => itemWhichChange.date[key] !== itemWhereChange.date[key])) {
    ...
}
```

Так же можно получить массив ключей через [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), при условии что нужно проверить **все** ключи

```js
const keys = Object.keys(itemWhichChange.date);
if (keys.some((key) => itemWhichChange.date[key] !== itemWhereChange.date[key])) {
    ...
}
```